# Theano installation corrupted after installing opencv

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, cuda, opencv

I've installed theano on ubuntu 16.04. I can specify the installation procedure later if required

Some of the system specs are as follows

```
Ubuntu 16.04
CUDA 7.5
NVIDIA Drivers 361
Python 2.7
```

The installation seems to have gone ahead smoothly and the testing script [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html) runs correctly and shows that the gpu is being used. After that I installed opencv as per the instructions given [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/). The site doesn't seem to be working right now so I'll list the instructions below

1. git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
2. cd opencv && git checkout 3.1.0 && cd ~
3. git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
4. cd opencv_contrib && git checkout 3.1.0 && cd ~
5. cd opencv && mkdir build && cd build
6. cmake
   -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
   -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
   -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF
   -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON
   -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules
   -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
   ..
7. make -j4   &&   sudo make install   &&   sudo ldconfig

After this, opencv is installed and runs fine.

However, after that, the initial theano setup does not work. When I run the gpu testing script above, I get the following error/warning

```
NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available  (error: Unable to get the number of gpus available: unknown error)
```

When I run nvidia-smi from the terminal, I get the following error

```
NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system. Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed and present in your system.
Please also try adding directory that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.
```

(And neither does sudo nvidia-smi)

And when I run the `deviceQuery` script from the Cuda Samples, I get the following error

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
 Result = FAIL
```

When I run `nvcc -V` , I get the expected output as follows

```
nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Any suggestions as to what could be going wrong? If required I can specify further details. A few addditional details

a) I am not using bumblebee

b) Installed Nvidia drivers from the Additional Drivers section in the Ubuntu Settings. However I don't think this is an issue as the gpu testing script runs absolutely fine.

c) In the opencv installation, I haven't specified a flag to use cuda, but I can clearly remember that during the build process, there were certain files containing cuda in their name that were part of the build process.

Thanks in Advance.